# Nodejs Opensearch client bulk create not waiting all documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, bulkinsert, opensearch

I am new to Opensearch and I am trying to create a NodeJS class to add many asynchronous documents to an index; I read the [bulk operations doc](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/javascript/helpers/) and thought that it covers my needs, especially because I understood that `flushInterval` controls the amount of time to wait before sending a request to opensearch server. I tested that my beliefs were wrong and I am not getting what the flush interval controls.

I would like to wait for a certain time to group events before sending to server reducing the calls. Is it something that I can do with bulk API itself or I need some wrapper code around it?